# JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

I've been wondering about what is wrong with my code

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter discount type");
                if(s == "PWD"){
                    dis = 0.25;
                }
                else{
                    dis = 0;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
                }
```

when I run my program, it performs the code in the 'else' block instead of doing what is in the 'if' block. Thanks!

Comment: it would be better if you show how you entering the string in the input dialog. i think you are missing the trailing spaces or small letters in entering and trying to check with capital letters if not that problem then try  `if(s.equals("PWD"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
`.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

`Objects.equals()` checks for nulls before calling .equals() so you don't have to (available as of JDK7, also available in Guava).

try like this 

`if(s.equals("PWD"))`

Comment: @iamLinker good question. keep posting the useful questions like this

Answer (score 2):

if you use:

s == "PWD"

java defines another String by "PWD" value and compare the references of s and the new var
you have to use:

```
s.equals("PWD")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using equals method of string.

```
`s.equals("PWD")` instead of `s == "PWD"` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` for case insensitive comparison.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

public class Testing {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double dis = 0;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter discount type");
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("PWD")){
        dis = 0.25;
    }
    else{
        dis = 0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
    }
    System.out.println(dis);
}
```

}

Try this I used .equalsIgnoreCase instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

`==` calling a reference similarity

and `.equals()` check the value similarity so its better to use a `(s.equals("PWD"))`

Comment: even better to use "PWD".equals(s) to avoid NullPointerException when s is null